# Аналог Firebug'а для других браузеров

Tags: плагин, firebug

Здравствуйте. Существует ли аналог плагина `Firebug` для браузеров `Chrome`, `Opera`? (Для `Chrome` я видел уже нечто похожее)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome: нажмите ctrl + shift + J. Это Web Inspector.
Opera: главное меню - страница - средства разработки - Open Opera Dragonfly.

Comment: Посмотрел. "Немного" уступают по функциональности `Firebug`'у. Кстати, исправьте у себя на `Ctrl+Shift+J`.

Comment: @alex_90 - значит вы так смотрели, лично я давным давно практически не использую firebug (разве что в лисе дебажу что-то, не более)

Причина популярности фаербага такая-же как и причина популярности Internet Explorer и Windows - они были первыми =)

Comment: Да, спасибо, поправил).

Comment: @AlexWindHope, для JavaScript разработчика Firebug однозначно лучше..) Лично мне Firebug-овский CSS редактор показался удобнее. Хотя когда я вижу как Рыжий Лис кушает 1,5ГБ оперативы, как раз приходят мысли поискать альтернативу.

Answer (score 1):

зачем? у хрома встроенный дебаггер отличный, у оперы тоже её DragonFly нормально работает, даже у ie есть дебаггер, конечно он по функционалу слабее но пользоваться можно.

Answer (score 1):

[firebugLite](http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/chrome/)

Comment: @Vfvtnjd, мне лень переводить. Там написано что он действует только для сайтов, расположенных на машина разработчика? Я прав?

Comment: да.это так.А вы как хотели вообще?